# The Google Drive folder is missing when folder browsing in Windows 8 metro

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, google-drive-api

When browsing folders using a Windows 8 metro application (for example attaching a file to an email or saving a PDF), strangely the Google Drive folder is missing and cannot be found.

The Google Drive folder works fine in the "desktop mode" however. I've tried this on 2 separate machines and accounts.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is what it could be causing that you cannot access your Google Drive. I assume you would like to know how you would be able to access your Google Drive from the Metro Interface.

You can add Google Drive to be included in your Documents Library by right clicking it in the explorer and to add the location of your Google Drive. If you then navigate to the Metro interface of Mail and navigate down to documents you should be able to find you documents and folders that are contained **within** your Google Drive.

Comment: Sure that is true, you can add the Google drive to the documents library and the contained files will be accessible from that library in the Metro interface.
I would still like to know why it doesn't appear when browsing the folder structure. How would you save in to Google drive from the Metro interface for example?